# Can I run a terminal command from ssh to open the browser on X server?

Tags: raspbian, display, terminal

I've hooked up the raspberry pi to a display. I have ssh'd in from another machine and I was wondering how, if possible, to open a browser window via `epiphany http://example.com` from my ssh session and have it appear on the screen.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Presuming you are logged in as the same user that's running the X display, this is fairly easy.  First you need to know the display identifier; if there is only one running instance, it is probably `:0`.  To check, use `who`.  You'll see output including stuff like this:

```
goldilocks   pts/5        2015-02-16 07:18 (:1)
goldilocks   pts/6        2015-02-16 07:18 (:1)
goldilocks   pts/7        2015-02-16 07:36 (:1)
```

The display identifier is in parenthesis at the end, in this case `:1`.  You need to set that in the environment of your ssh session.  For most shells including bash (the default on raspbian):

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

Or `:1`, as the case may be.  To now start epiphany there:

```
epiphany http://example.com &
```

The `&` backgrounds this, otherwise it will block and you won't get the prompt back in `ssh`.

Answer (score 9):

As an addition to [Goldilocks' answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/27881/5670), for epiphany you can set the display using the `--display` option:

```
epiphany --display=:0 http://example.com &
```

Comment: …but this solution only works with epiphany?!

Comment: Works with chromium-browser as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
ssh -o ForwardX11=yes pi@192.168.0.37
```

Open an ssh with X11 port forwarding and you can run some Xwindows command  from the terminal

```
ssh -o ForwardX11=yes <userName>@<your pi's hostname or ip address>
```

Comment: I don't think this is an answer to the question.  The OP is asking how to start applications *on the remote display* (i.e., the one attached to the pi) via `ssh` from another machine.  X11 forwarding is about running remote GUI applications on the *local* display.

Comment: Use `ssh -X pi@192.168.0.37` if you are in hurry. (and I agree with  @goldilocks: seems he want's to display epiphany on the remote display)